# How to store fermenter after use

Tags: storage, fermenter, beginner

I have two plastic fermenters and am wondering the best way to store them when I am not using them? Sometimes I don't get the opportunity to use them for a few months (longest was up to 1 year) so what is the best way to look after them while not in use?

After each use I will rinse with hot water and then screw the taps on, then use cling film/plastic wrap on the top then add the lid.

Comment: What's the reason for using plastic wrap?

Comment: I normally store the fermenter in the garden shed which is outside and with no air lock so there is a hole where anything can get in. By adding the plastic wrap is closes the hole and by putting the tap back on there is no way anything can get in.

Comment: Hi guys, all the answers sound good to me but they all have the same amounts of votes. I think I will leave the question open for awhile and see who gets the votes before I decide who to give the answer to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you do a good job cleaning by dismantling the tap, and that's really the key - storing the fermentor clean so that it can be effectively sanitized when next needed.

Make sure it is drained and completely air dry before adding any seal or you'll get stale water in there. That can mean another round of cleaning to get rid of the odor.

Comment: Yes I normally try to towel then air dry before sealing it up.

Answer (score 3):

In [20 Tips for Better Brewing (Brew Your Own, December 1995)](http://byo.com/stories/issue/item/33-20-tips-for-better-brewing), the author says you should fill the buckets to the brim with a dilute bleach-water solution (one teaspoon per gallon of water) and seal them up; then rinse with hot water on your next brew day:

Personally, I found that recommendation surpising.  Maybe make sure your fermenters air-dry really well, and then seal them up with a dessicant pack inside?

Answer (score 3):

I normally clean and sanitize my fermentors and carboys after use (along with all other brew accessories) and then I let everything air dry (or dry with paper towels). Then I store them in [large plastic storage totes](http://www.lowes.com/pd_503451-61896-503451-120_0__?productId=4774891&Ntt=plastic%20storage%20totes&pl=1&currentURL=?Ntt=plastic%2bstorage%2btotes&facetInfo=) that have lids that snap on.  This has worked great for me.  Also, they make [long shallow totes](http://www.lowes.com/ProductDisplay?partNumber=128404-62860-7104HFT-010-111-044&langId=-1&storeId=10151&productId=4323739&catalogId=10051&cmRelshp=req&rel=nofollow&cId=PDIO1) that work great for racking canes and mash paddles, etc.  Tools that are too long for the normal bins.